# making a multiple checkbox sticky

Tags: php, html

I have a form which I want to make sticky. It has lots of check boxes:

```
<label><span>ASD</span></label><input type="checkbox"  name="condition[]" value="ASD" <?php if (in_array("ASD", $_POST['condition'])) echo 'checked'; ?> /><br />
<label><span>SLC</span></label><input type="checkbox"  name="condition[]" value="SLC" <?php if (in_array("SLC", $_POST['condition'])) echo 'checked'; ?> /><br />...
```

Upon submit this works fine expect if the user makes no selection. I think this is something to do with the fact that the array is empty. I get an error:

> Undefined index: condition

and also

> in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if the `condition` array was passed and if it was not make it an empty `array`

`if(!isset($_POST['condition'])) { $_POST['condition'] = array(); }`

Answer (score 1):

If the user doesn't make a selection, `$_POST['condition']` will not be defined.  This is a simple fix by adding:

```
if (!isset($_POST['condition'])) $_POST['condition'] = [];
```

to your script.

Answer (score 1):

This is because:
1) If user does not make any selection the "condition" would not be defined.
2) You are using in_array which require second parameter of type array.
But in case user does not make any selection this parameter will have undefined variable as  parameter.

So you can use:

```
<label><span>ASD</span></label><input type="checkbox"  name="condition[]" value="ASD" <?php if (!empty($_POST['condition']) && in_array("ASD", $_POST['condition'])) echo 'checked'; ?> /><br />
```

SLC />
...